# Flutter: SetState() reloading widget onTap():

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, setstate

***Ask for any additional Information ( im new to this, so I might not understand some things)***

I am doing a query to extract products from database. I return products with ListView.builder. But I added the posibility to press on them so i can display more information about products in Bottom Container.

**Situation:** I Scroll in my List but when I need additional Info about a Product, I press on it and product info is displayed in bottom Container, but whenether I press, the Widget with Query is Reloading causing to wait before I see the list again.

I use setState that cause me the reload, but I dont know how to fix this.

***I need to Reload only information in Yellow (amber) Container!!!!***

[image: Reloads on Pressed]

[image: onTap]

**CODE:**

```js
Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<List?>(
                future: read(
                    "SELECT ProductAdress, ProductName, NeedCount, ScanCount FROM ScanRest WHERE ProductStation = '${widget.nrStatie}' AND BoxID = '${cutieScan}' ORDER BY ProductName ASC;"),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return const Text('Loading....');
                    default:
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        print("call error");
                        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      } else {
                        print("call success = ${snapshot.data}");
                        List data = snapshot.data ?? [];
                        return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Card(
                                elevation: 2,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {



                  // --------------------problem------------------------
                                    setState(() {
                                      test = (data[index] as Map)['ProductName']
                                          .toString();
                                      denumProdus = (data[index]
                                              as Map)['ProductSeriesDescr']
                                          .toString();
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Row(children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Text(
                                          (data[index] as Map)['ProductAdress']
                                              .toString()),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 5,
                                      child: Text(
                                          (data[index] as Map)['ProductName']
                                              .toString()),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                            (data[index] as Map)['NeedCount']
                                                .toString()),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                            (data[index] as Map)['ScanCount']
                                                .toString()),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      }
                  }
                }),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: !vizibil,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [Text('${test}'), Text('${denumProdus}')],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: This is broken; `future: read(
                    "SELECT ProductAdress, ProductName, NeedCount, ScanCount FROM ScanRest WHERE ProductStation = '${widget.nrStatie}' AND BoxID = '${cutieScan}' ORDER BY ProductName ASC;"),`

DO NOT create the future in the future: parameter of a FutureBuilder.  Watch this video for details https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 0):

Calling SetState() causes the whole page to reload, so what you are experiencing is the expected behaviour.

To achieve your goal, you need to look into [State Management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt).

It's a big an complex topic, and requires some time to correctly be understood, but you can't go without it, expecially as your application grows.

Answer (score 0):

That's because calling 'setState' rebuilds the entire 'Build' method.
And you have put every thing together.

What you could do is, either

1. load the data into a list with in,

   @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
   // call a method to get data list in here
   }

and populate ListBuilder using that data.

2. or, use Provider pattern and put the bottom container within Consumer<>

   [provider](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)